# Retrieving items from AppleScript record

Tags: arrays, applescript, records

I have an AppleScript record, myJSON, which I've created from a JSON entry using JSON Helper:

```
{"height":200.0,"width":300.0,"productoption":["fabric","rectangle","roll"],"id":33,"product":["backdrop"]}
```

I can easily access all the keys with a single entry by using, for example,

```
product of myJSON
```

I can't figure out how to access the productoption key which has a multiple entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's exactly the same way, the value for key `productoption` is an array (`list` in AppleScript terms)

```
set options to productoption of myJSON
repeat with anOption in options
    display dialog anOption
end repeat
```